# AspectJ \ Spring AOP - replacing whole method

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj

I have the following method:

```
 public ClassifyCamel(Camel camel) {

    if (camel.isHavingSingleHump()) {
       return SINGLE_HUMP_CAMEL;
    }        
 }
```

Is it possible to create an aspect that replaces the whole method logic? for example:

```
 @Aspect
 .
 .

 @Before("ClassifyCamel") {

   if (camel.isRich) {
     return RICH_CAMEL;
   }
 }
```

Best.

Comment: If you use `@Around` you can choose not to invoke the advised method.

Answer (score 4):

You can use **@Around** advice in order to execute some log before and after your method execution.

Here you can check an example:

```
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {

   @Around("execution(* com.yourPackage.YourClass.yourMethod(..))")
   public void logAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {

    System.out.println("Around before is running!");

    /*
     *  IF YOU DON'T DO THIS YOU CAN SKIP YOUR METHOD EXECUTION. 
     * You can do whatever you need
     */
    joinPoint.proceed(); //execute the method. 

    System.out.println("Around after is running!");

   }

}
```

Hope to help